# Cant set a Windows-based path in gradle.properties

Tags: java, windows, android-studio, gradle

This has been answered a million times, but ONLY for Linux.  I'm building with Android Studio 2.2.3 on Windows 10.

I keep getting the following error when trying to build my APK.

```
Error:Failed to complete Gradle execution.

Cause:
Java home supplied via 'org.gradle.java.home' is invalid. Invalid directory: C:Program FilesJavajdk1.8.0_121
```

This is the line in question in "gradle.properties"

```
org.gradle.java.home=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121
```

I also get an error saying "Invalid string escape" using those backslashes.  As far as I can tell, there is no way to set a Windows-based path for "org.gradle.java.home".

I've been hacking away at this for almost 2 hours, and I'm getting nowhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

please try org.gradle.java.home=C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_121

Comment: Yeah, that did it.  I must have typed it wrong or something when I tried that before.  I'm actually quite surprised that it accepts forward slashes as a Windows path.  That's a first.

Comment: @Noah Java (and therefore Groovy and Gradle) always accepted forward slashes as file separators.

Comment: This worked for me: org.gradle.java.home=C\:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_152

Answer (score 1):

Backslashes have special meaning in properties files. See [Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html)

Since java (and therefore groovy) accepts both back and forward slashes for file separator, I suggest you instead use forward slashes.